# Choose between implementations at compile time

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Say one wants to create a C++ class with two separate implementations (say one to run on a CPU and on a GPU) and one wants this to happen at compile time.

What design pattern can be used for this?

Comment: No design pattern needed if you want to decide at compile time. Just instantiate the implementation you want. If you want this done by switching some "setting" in the source file, then you can use a simple template (or ifdef for `C` style).

Comment: Won't a template be decide at run time? could give an example (I'll accept that as an answer).

Comment: C++ templates are compile-time entities.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A good book to read is: Modern C++ Design: Generic Programming and Design Patterns Applied, written by Andrei Alexandrescu.

Basicly he said that you can implement what you want using policy based class (a kind of strategy pattern, but done at compilation time. Bellow is a simple example showing this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct CPU
{
  // Actions that CPU must do (low level)
  static T doStuff() {cout << "CPU" << endl;};
};

template <typename T>
struct GPU
{
  // Actions that GPU must do (low level)
  // Keeping the same signatures with struct CPU will enable the strategy design patterns
  static T doStuff() {cout << "GPU" << endl;};
};

template <typename T, template <class> class LowLevel>
struct Processors : public LowLevel<T>
{
  // Functions that any processor must do
  void process() {
    // do anything and call specific low level
    LowLevel<T>::doStuff();
  };
};

int main()
{
  Processors<int, CPU> cpu;
  Processors<int, GPU> gpu;

  gpu.process();
  cpu.process();
}
```

Comment: The complicated part of this, for me, is that I want compilation toolchain to inject the strategy choice.  I end up falling back to macros, and I lose the policy abstraction.

Answer (score 4):

Simplest solution example, using the [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern (however, it's irrelevant whether it's compile-time or run-time chosen):

```
class BaseStrategy
{
  public:
    virtual void doStuff() = 0;  
};

class Strategy1 : public Base
{
  public:
    void doStuff();
};

class Strategy2 : public Base
{
  public:
    void doStuff();
};

class SomeKindOfAMainClass
{
  public:
    SomeKindOfAMainClass(BaseStrategy* s)
    {
      this->s = s; 
    }
    void doStuff()
    {
      s->doStuff();
    }
  private:
    BaseStrategy* s;
};
```

and then you just do either `new SomeKindOfAMainClass(new Strategy1())` or `new SomeKindOfAMainClass(new Strategy2())`.

Simple example of traits:

```
struct WithStrategy1 {};
struct WithStrategy2 {};

template<typename T>
class SomeKindOfAMainClass;

template<>
class SomeKindOfAMainClass<WithStrategy1>
{
  //use Strategy1 here
};

template<>
class SomeKindOfAMainClass<WithStrategy2>
{
  //use Strategy2 here
};
```

And you just either instantiate `SomeKindOfAMainClass<WithStrategy1>` or `SomeKindOfAMainClass<WithStrategy2>` at the beginning of your program.

Or you can have the solution given by Omaha with `#ifdef`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple template for that.
(Sorry for the crude implementation, this is just an example)

```
#include <iostream>
struct example
{
    void cpu() { std::cout << "Cpu\n"; }
    void gpu() { std::cout << "Gpu\n"; }

    template<bool useGpu = true>void go() { gpu(); }
};
template<>void example::go<false>() { cpu(); }

int main()
{
    example().go<false>(); //<-- Prints 'Cpu'
    example().go(); // <-- Prints 'Gpu'
}
```

Comment: hmm.. what if you had a lot of functions? you'ld have to to create three functions for each functionality instead of two with the if else method

Comment: My example covered simpy choosing between 2 methods. For what you want you might want to specialize a class with multiple methods in it. BartoszKP's answer is more oriented then to what you are looking for...

Comment: @nbubis: you won't have to write cpu() and gpu() with full implementation in this example. The core functionality would be in a separate function: it will be called directly from cpu() and called via a __kernel__ function submitted to GPU from gpu(). Basically only bookkeeping necessary for GPU submissions would need to be written separately (they always are); the rest can be common.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make compile-time decisions, there is always the old standby:  the preprocessor.  Use `#ifdef`/`#endif` blocks and compiler arguments to specify the code you want.